# Android Canvas: Drawing a circle only on transparent background

Tags: java, android, background, android-canvas, transparent

I have a canvas in Android where I draw many circles with 1 to 10px diameter.

I only want to print this circle on transparent background, if there is any other color anywhere at the place where the circle would be painted, it should be canceled and I want to know the color which is on that place already. Also when its just overlapping a little bit.

The problem is, alle the methods I have found have a bad performance.

I'm painting more than 10000 circles on the screen, that works fine, but they are overlapping and I have to handle that problem.

Can anyone help me?? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear.

If you want to know which color is present "before the background of the view is drawn", I don't see any solution. I would be very interested if someone could find an answer to that.

If you want to know "if you previously drew a circle that would overlap with the current circle you want to draw", then the best solution is to maintain, yourself, programmatically, a list of all circles you drew before, their centers locations and diameters and check if it will overlap with a new circle. That computation is pretty easy and should be fast enough, even for 1 000 circles.

Also note that there are some ways to optimize such a computation. For instance, you could consider, if things are too slow, to use a different distance measure instead of the classic euclidian measure. For instance, the difference of x and y, using absolute values, between centers could be used instead of the square root of the sum of the square of their differences.